# Explaining the $K$ functor isomorphism $K(X) \cong \tilde{K}(X) \oplus \Bbb Z$

Tags: algebraic-topology, direct-sum, topological-k-theory

It seems unclear to me what the [splitting means in page 40, of Hatcher's](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf) for a $K$ functor.

1. There is a natural homomorphism, $\varphi:K(X)\rightarrow \tilde{K}(X)$, sending $[E-\epsilon^n] \rightarrow [E]$ and also
   $$ \ker \varphi \cong \Bbb Z$$
2. There is an inclusion map $i:\{x_0\} \rightarrow X$ thus inducing a map $K(X) \rightarrow K(x_0)$ which is the restriction bundle.
   $$[E-\epsilon^n] \mapsto [i^*(E)-i^*(\epsilon^n) ]= [E|_{x_0} - \epsilon^n|_{x_0} ]$$
   also gives
   $$ K(x_0) \cong \Bbb Z$$

> This induces a splitting $$K(X) \cong \tilde{K}(X) \oplus \Bbb Z.$$

So how does this induce a splitting? What are the explicit maps?

---

EDIT: after correction.

When $i^*$ restricted induces isomoprhism $\psi : \ker \varphi \rightarrow K(x_0)$ Thus, there is a well -defined inverse

$$ 0 \rightarrow  K(x_0) \xrightarrow{\psi^{-1}} K(X) \xrightarrow{\varphi} \tilde{K}(X) \rightarrow 0 $$

The left splitting representation is thus given by
$$ ([E-E']-\psi^{-1}i^*[E-E']) \oplus \psi^{-1}i^*[E-\epsilon^n]  = ([E-E'] - [\epsilon^m-\epsilon^n]) + [\epsilon^m - \epsilon^n]$$
where $m,n$ are the ranks of the bundles $E$, $E'$ over $x_0$ respectively.

---

**Addendum question:** The above method, and that shown in the reply produces a splitting that is actually independent of the choice of base point $x_0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The splitting $K(X)\to\ker\varphi=\mathbb{Z}$ of the short exact sequence
$$
0\to\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\iota} K(X)\xrightarrow{\varphi}\tilde{K}(X)\to 0
$$
is the second map $i^*\colon K(X)\to K(x_0)\cong\mathbb{Z}$.  You can check that this is indeed a splitting (i.e., $i^*\iota$ is the identity on $\ker\varphi$).

Explcitly, the isomorphism $K(X)\cong\tilde{K}(X)\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is $[E]_{\approx_s}\mapsto ([E]_{\sim},r)$ where $r$ is the *virtual rank* of $E$ (at $x_0$), i.e., if $E\approx_s E_1-E_2$ where $E_1,E_2$ are vector bundles over $X$, then $r=\operatorname{rank} E_1-\operatorname{rank} E_2$ (taken at the fiber over $x_0$).

**Addendum**

The splitting is dependent on the component of $x_0$, but that is the cost Hatcher is paying for allowing the base $X$ to be disconnected here.  Expanding that a little, the other splitting map $\tilde{K}(X)\to K(X)$ is determined by the component of $x_0$ because we want that copy to have virtual rank $0$ at $x_0$.  In fact, you can split off a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ for each component of $X$, mirroring the possibility of different rank on different components as discussed in page 39.

Comment: I did not see this post when I was making this edit. I wonder if you mind giving mine a check, but the ideas are essentially the same, I think. In this case, the splitting does not really depend on the choice of base point does it? i.e. the "outcome" is the same for any choice of splitting?

Comment: That is mostly fine, except you notation (the $\varepsilon^m$) seems to assume $E$ is actually a vector bundle rather than the formal difference of two vector bundles?

Comment: I wrote after the equation that any element in $K(X)$ can be written in the form $[E-\epsilon^n]$, which allows us to make the transformation. But, as I asked in addendum - the result actually doesn't depend on choice of base does it?

Comment: So you are assuming $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite-dimensional CW complex?  Otherwise, if $E'$ has no complementary vector bundle in any finite-rank trivial bundle, then subtracting $E'$ cannot be rewritten as subtracting trivial bundles.

Comment: I've added a few words about the role of the base point in the splitting.

Comment: Yes, thank you!  The fact that elements in $K(X)$ are of form $[E-\epsilon^n] $ in page 40.  You are right, I made a mistake, I thougth that $E$ has constant rank - which is not the case. 

 I have edited my proof again. Sorry, now I still have a concern, is the "virtual rank" $r= rank E_1 - rank E_2$ well defined? should not it depend on the component? (I am supposing that you take an element $E_1 - E_2 \in K(X)$. )

Comment: Yes, everything is taken at the fiber over $x_0$.  Sorry didn't make that explicit.

Comment: If you have time, I would be happy if you look at my other concern on hather's text: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2927513/short-exact-sequence-of-k-functor-applying-tietze-extension