# Short exact sequence of $K$ functor; applying Tietze extension

Tags: general-topology, analysis, vector-bundles, topological-k-theory

I have questions in  [page 52 of Hatcher's](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf), for the proof of Proposition 2.9

> If $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $A \subseteq X$ is a closed subspace, then the inclusion and quotient maps $$A \xrightarrow{i}X \xrightarrow{q} X/A$$ induce homomoprhisms $$\tilde{ K}(X/A) \xrightarrow{q^*} \tilde{ K}(X) \xrightarrow{i^*} \tilde{ K}(A)$$

He makes the following claim.

In showing that $\ker i^* \subseteq im \, q^*$, he applied the Tietze extension theorem.

> $E$ is trivial over $A$ implies there are sections $s_i$. Choose a cover of $A$ by open sets $U_j$ in $X$ over each of which $E$ is trivial over. We may regard restrictions $s_{ij}:A \cap U_j \rightarrow E$ as maps into a single fiber. i.e. 
>   $$ s_{ij} :A \cap U_j \rightarrow \Bbb C^n$$ 
>   By the **Tietze extension theorem** we may extend this to $s_{ij} :U_j \rightarrow \Bbb C^n$.

But why can we apply? [Tietze extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem) requires $U_j$ to be **normal**, it is only a open  subset of a compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: At a glance I guess not. I think you can take the one point compactification of a non-paracompact, locally compact Hausdorff space. I guess you should assume $X$ is hereditarily paracompact.

Comment: @MikeMiller Hatcher assumes that $X$ is  compact Hausdorff.

Comment: @Paul I believe that what I just described is a compact Hausdorff space which contains a non-paracompact open subset, so that you may not apply Tietze to that subset. No? In any case, your answer shows the assumption in my comment is unnecessary.

Comment: @MikeMiller Ah, you are right. If we know that all open subspaces of $X$ are normal, then we can apply Tietze. Such $X$ are precisely the hereditarily normal spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, Hatcher is again a little imprecise, and in the present form it does not work. Let us repair it.

For each $x \in A$ choose an open neighborhood $V(x)$ in $X$ over which $E$ is trivial. Next choose a neigborhood $U(x)$ such that $\overline{U(x)} \subset V(x)$. Then the $U(x)$ cover $A$. Now Tietze's extension theorem applies to give extensions $s'_{ix} : \overline{U(x)} \to \mathbb{C}^n$ of $s_i \mid_{A \cap \overline{U(x)}} : A \cap \overline{U(x)}  \to \mathbb{C}^n$. Then $s_{ix} = s'_{ix} \mid_{U(x)} : U(x) \to \mathbb{C}^n$ extends $s_i \mid_{A \cap U(x)} : A \cap U(x)  \to \mathbb{C}^n$. Now you are in the adequate position to proceed like Hatcher.

Up to this point the argument works for any normal $X$. In the following step a partition of unity is used which requires $X$ paracompact.

Answer (score 0):

Just note the following facts:

- A compact Hausdorff space is normal, thus completely regular;
- Any subspace of completely regular space is completely regular;
- On a completely regular space, the Urysohn lemma applies, and hence the Tietze extension theorem.